# Is it possible to track the progress of ObjectContext.SaveChanges?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm working on a small console utility to upload batches of data to our hosted SQL server. The total data size can get up to several megabytes. I'd like a way to display the progress of the SaveChanges operation. Is there any way I can do this with the Entity Framework? If not, any recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'm presuming that when you say "batches of data" you mean multiple records, rather than one record with a very large blob on it. There's probably nothing you can do in the latter case. But in the former case...

If it takes long enough that you even care, I would seriously consider stepping outside of the Entity Framework, and using one of the (many) SQL Server bulk insert facilities, as it will *considerably* speed up the insert, which will probably make your users happier than a progress bar would.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. So something like SqlBulkCopy, then?

Comment: Something like that, yes. There are several choices.